# Windows store app Customise Template inside a ScrollViewer without breaking the UI virtualzation

Tags: windows-store-apps, ui-virtualization

I am working on a windows store metro style app and I have implemented an endless scrolling GridView on a listing page.

It works until user navigate "BACK" to a listing page with large amount of records. e.g. They have previously scroll to page 100.

I currently have code like this

```
    <ScrollViewer>
      <StackPanel>
        <Rectangle Width="100"/> //could be anything
        <ItemsPresenter/>
      </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

and according to this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh994637.aspx), above code will disable the UI virtualzation

if I change it to the following, it works but I lost the padding at start of the list.

```
    <ScrollViewer>
      <ItemsPresenter/>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Basically I want to display something before the list starts and it needs to be part of the scrollable viewport, so it can be scrolled away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a Margin to the `ItemsPresenter`:

`<ItemsPresenter Margin="100,0,0,0"/>` for a left space (though it looks like you're doing a top space...)

`<ItemsPresenter Margin="0,100,0,0"/>`